# Visual Studio popup line "3 of 17 std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>operator<<(double_val)"

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am new to Visual Studio and novice programmer. 
I have looked and looked through the options and cannot figure out how to turn off a single line popup that lists 1-17 things. 
It seems to come up only when I'm filling out a string to a cout variable. 
And it always says something like this:

3 of 17 std::basic_ostream>operator<<(double_val)

It irritating that I cant figure out 1) What it's helping me to know and 2) how to get rid of it.

Any help is appreciated. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcG4O.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's IntelliSense listing the acceptable parameter types for the stream insertion operator : int, double, string etc.
Now getting it is weird and it suggests you're calling the '<<' operator as a method, i.e. `cout .operator<<("a string")`. It doesn't happen if you use the more usual form of `cout << "a string"`

Most people find IntelliSense useful but you can turn it off. Go to Tools/Options and then to Text Edition -> C/C++ -> General. Clear the check box for Parameter information in the Statement Completion section. Note that you will lose IntelliSense for all function parameters, not just ostream.